# How can i download a .mat file from a website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I was trying to do that task with Matlab using :

```
url = 'the url of the file';
file_name = 'data.mat';
outfilename = websave(filename,url);
load(outfilename);
```

but it didn't work, how can i do that using python? kindly note i want the .mat as it is not an html , csv or any other format i just that file just downloaded(i can do it manually but i have hundreds that's why i need that)
.(python 3)

Comment: You must reference to your previous answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51453904/3768871

Answer (score 0):

using `urllib2`:

```
import urllib2

    response = urllib2.urlopen("the url")
    file = open("filename.mat", 'w')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
```

Comment: can you please fix the indentation in the answer. I am not able to fix it because of changes less than 6 characters. thanks.